# N-tier application and SQL Server Compact 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce, connection-string, n-tier-architecture

I am currently developing some application in C# and I am using a n-tier architecture and embedded database SQL Server Compact. SQL Server Compact is pretty new to me, and I have some problem with connection string to this database. My n-tier application consists from `DataTier`, `MiddleTier`, `PresentationTier`. Every layer is separate project in solution.

`DataTier` contains the db file `db.sdf` and files for EF 5.0 including entities. Model was created with a database-first approach.

I had idea that I can build this embedded database directly into `dataTier.dll` and reference to it from other layers but I don't want to make connection string absolute, so I currently using connection string in this form:

```
Data Source = |DataDirectory|\db.sdf
```

in every layer, which is nonsense cause it creates separate database for each layer, but I can not find out how to make connection string relatively to database in `dataTier`. Is that even possible?

Could you point me to right direction or what is best approach to this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Well, your data tier should expose a general-purpose interface to the higher layers - something like a **repository** or something similar - that doesn't require any of the other tiers to know about what database is being used (and therefore they shouldn't need the connection string, either!)

Comment: I have managers in middleTier to work with db but when I want to test in unit tests it throws exception no connections string defined.... So if I understand it right , connection string should be only in dataTier?